# Find records that have two exact instances of a many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an application with a business logic concerning products with multiple variants:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :variant
end

class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  has_many :variant_option_values
  has_many :option_values, through: :variant_option_values
  has_many :prices
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :product_option_types
  has_many :option_types, through: :product_option_types
  has_many :variants
end

class OptionValue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :option_type
end

class OptionType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_option_types
  has_many :products, through: :product_option_types
  has_many :option_values
end

class ProductOptionType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :option_type
end

class VariantOptionValue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :variant
  belongs_to :option_value
end
```

The ERD looks like this:
[image]

Having a product `product_1` how can I find its variants that have `OptionValue` instances `option_value_1`, `option_value_2` and `option_value_3`? Note that the variant has to have all three option values at the same time and can have more than those three (but not necessarily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
option_values = [option_value_1, option_value_2, option_value_3]

Variant.include(product: [option_types: :option_values])
  .where("option_values.id IN (?)", option_values.map(&:id))
  .group("products.id")
  .having("count(*) >= ?", option_values.size)
```

Comment: This query finds products having given option values. I want to find variants of given product having those option values.

Comment: That's nice. However, you assume here that the variant has only those three option values. What about the cases, when the variant has the three option values but also others?

Comment: @pmichna for this case I assume you can just change "count(*) = ?" to "count(*) >= ?"